# Migration/conversion from BIND9 Mysql to BIND9 Zone files

Tags: mysql, dns, cpanel, bind

I have searched for a solution to my problem. 
but can't find one.

We have been hosting websites on Mac's,(Not my choice) and are now moving to cPanel. 
one of the things that are currently hosting on mac's, is our nameservers(NS1-4).
They run Bind, which is looking in a MySql database, in the migration from mac's to totally running in cPanel, i would like to move out NS into cPanel DNSonly.

But how can i import/convert these mysql strings, so i can use them in cpanel which as far as i know, is using zone files, stored in /var/named/.....

And easy and stable solutions ?

Comment: It's unlikely you will find any tools to do that. You can read config from MySQL and place them in the appropriate config file in the other system, right? If you cannot, either learn how zone config for DNS works or have someone do it for you.

Comment: Can you try doing an AXFR (zone transfer) from the current nameservers? That will give you the zone in zonefile format so you will just have to save the resulting output to a file.

Comment: +1: AXFR looks like the easiest way if axfr is allowed by name server configuration. Use `dig axfr your.example.domain.com`

Comment: @PatrickMevzek i have used your solution. 
Works like a charm, for the most of it, have some æøå domains, which i need to convert, and som other work, removing som bottom lines, because there is 2x SOA. 

But that's fine, the next problem, is locating the httpr records in cpanel, but as far as exporting the DNS records, the DIG works! :)